# Use sed to concatenate xml tags

Tags: xml, bash, unix, sed

I am trying to extract and concatenate  values of `<id>` and `<name>` from the below xml tags

```
<applications><application>
  <id>292</id>
  <name>Test</name>
  <accountGuid>2-b01e-2ef14d11c5e0</accountGuid>
</application>
<application>
  <id>195</id>
  <name>State</name>
  <accountGuid>2-b01e-2ef14d11c5e0</accountGuid>
</application>
<application>
  <id>266</id>
  <name>Home</name>
  <accountGuid>2-b01e-2ef14d11c5e0</accountGuid>
</application>
</applications>
```

Desired output is

```
292:Test
195:state
266:Home
```

I used the below sed to extract, But it gives me the the output as

> `sed -n 's:.*<id>\(.*\)</id>.*:\1:p;s:.*<name>\(.*\)</name>.*:\1:p'`

```
292
Test
195
state
266
Home
```

Can You guys please help to know what should I do to get the output desired ?

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 2):

With xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet select --text --template --match "/applications/application" --value-of "concat(id,':',name)" -n file.xml
```

Output:

```
292:Test
195:State
266:Home
```

See: `xmlstarlet select --help`